# $wpdb->insert is not working

Tags: database, wpdb

I just created an theme and make a form that action is options.php but it gives an error of options page is not found. So I decided to make own table inside wp-database by this code using creation of plugin:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'create_javart_theme_settings_table');

function create_javart_theme_settings_table() {

global $wpdb;

$version = get_option('my_plugin_version', '1.0');
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'javart_theme_settings_table';

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
    id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(200) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    value longtext NOT NULL,
    type varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) $charset_collate;";

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta($sql);

update_option('my_plugin_version', $version);
}
```

and this code works fine make a table for me, but when I insert data from the form the page refreshes but nothing is goes to wordpress db.

The form is:

```
    <form method="post" action="">
        <p>About Us Diagram &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="title" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" /><input type="text" name="content" placeholder="Content" /></p>
            <?php submit_button('Save Settings'); ?>
    </form>
```

and php code to retrieve this content is

```
<?php
$titleData = $_POST['title'];
$contentData = $POST['content'];
?>
```

and reenter to plugin, in plugin to insert the values the code is:

```
function about_us_form_to_database_exporter() {

global $titleData;
global $contentData;
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->show_errors();
$wpdb->last_query;


$type = 'About Us';
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'javart_theme_settings_table';
$wpdb->insert(
$table_name, array(
'name' => 'Title',
'value' => $titleData,
'type' => 'About Us',
)
);

$wpdb->print_error();
var_dump($wpdb);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'about_us_form_to_database_exporter');
```

then, what is the error that the input not going to wordpress database's table

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like it would be simpler to go back and fix your initial try: saving an option to a WP-native table rather than creating your own. Try [update_option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) - it creates an option if it doesn't exist, or updates if it does. This will save you a lot of code and headaches in the future.